# Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'

Tags: typescript, ionic2

How should I handle the Typescript error:

```
Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'
```

My code looks like this:

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {SocialSharing} from "ionic-native";

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/about/about.html'
})
export class AboutPage {

  constructor() {

  }

  share() {
    SocialSharing.share('Take a look at our app. It is great! Download it from the App Store now.',
        'Take a look at our app. It is great! Download it from the App Store now.', null, null).then(
          res => {},
          err => {}
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of the function `share` returns void as you can also see in the error message

```
static share (message?: string, subject?: string, file?: string|Array<string>, url?: string): void {}
```

Therefore you cannot call `then` when calling `share`

Comment: According to the ionic 2 documentation for ionic-native the plugins are wrapped in a promise so 'then' is the correct way to use it I think. http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/

Comment: You can be right but the implementation says something different. That is the only explanation for what is happening. Take a look here https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-native/blob/master/src/plugins/socialsharing.ts

Comment: I guess the wrapping thing is not applicable to all functions. If you check the implementation of the example `Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then...` you will see the method `getCurrentPosition` actually returns a Promise, which is not happening with `share`. I would ask in github it could be a bug

Comment: Many thanks for clarifying that. Makes sense now. I have removed the then.