# Angular2 - 'then' does not exist on type 'void'

Tags: angular, typescript

I try simple app where I delete user after clicking on delete button.

When I try to run server like this I get error on `then` in `deleteUser()`
component:

```
 deleteUser(user: User, event: any) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.userService
      .deleteUser(user)
      .then(res => {
        this.httpUsers = this.httpUsers.filter(h => h !== user);
        if (this.selectedUser === user) { this.selectedUser = null; }
      })
      .catch(error => this.error = error);
  }
```

service:

```
  deleteUser(user: User) {
    console.log('Deleting user');
  }
```

Error message:

> app/users.component.ts(46,8): error TS2339: Property 'then' does not
>   exist on type 'void'.

Line 46 from error is one above with `.then(res => {`

While googling I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37986102/property-then-does-not-exist-on-type-void) so I removed void from deleteUser function, however nothing changed.

**Any hint what I'm doing wrong?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to call the delete method so it will return the promise and you can use `.then(` you have to do like this

```
deleteUser(user: User) {
   return this.http.delete(url+id,...).toPromise();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use then if you are returning a promise. You can use subscribe if you are calling a REST API and then mapping the result

#### Using then

Service method

```
  getAudits() {
    // console.log('audits' + amplify.store('audits'));
    let audits: Audit[] = amplify.store('audits'));    
    return Promise.resolve(audits);
  }
```

Component

```
this.auditService.getAudits().then(audits => {
  this.audits = audits;
  this.updateChart(true);
});
```

#### Using subscribe

Service method

```
  getAudits() {
    return this.http.get('/rest/batch').map(res => res.json());
  }
```

Component

```
this.auditService.getAudits().subscribe(audits => {
  this.audits = audits;
  this.updateChart(true);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The `deleteUser` method in your service doesn't return a `Promise`, so you can't call `.then(res => ...)` on it, like the error states.

```
deleteUser(user: User) {
  console.log('Deleting user'); // <-- no return call - defaults to void
}
```