# How do I use "then" with TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, firebase

I'm converting a React app from pure JS to TypeScript. It's linked to firebase; the firebase functions are in a separate file.  The one I'm currently working on is to allow the user to change their password.  I have a form which accepts the new password and saves it (there's also some validation, but I've left that out).  In pure js, it all works fine, but when I convert to TypeScript I'm getting stuck on what to do with the "then" part.

So far my js files are as follows.

PasswordForm.js (so this was originally a js file, which I've changed to tsx; I've added a couple of interfaces and used them, but that's all I've changed):

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { withFirebase } from '../Firebase';

interface FormProps {
  firebase: {
    doPasswordUpdate: (string) => void  // Not sure about this line
  }
}

interface FormState {
  password: string
}

const INITIAL_STATE: FormState = {
  password: ""
};

const ChangePasswordForm = ({ firebase }: FormProps) => {

  const [formValues,  setFormValues]  = useState(INITIAL_STATE);


  const handleSubmit = event => {
  
      firebase
        .doPasswordUpdate(formValues.password)
        .then(() => {                // THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM HAPPENS
            ... do other things ...
        })
        .catch(error => {...});
  
  };

  return (
    <form 
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        name="password"
        value={formValues.password}
      />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );

  export default withFirebase(ChangePasswordForm);
```

My firebase functions are wrapped in a Context, but the actual functions are in firebase.js (I haven't done anything to convert this to TypeScript):

```
import app from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/database';

const config = {...}; // Firebase keys etc

class Firebase {
  constructor() {
    app.initializeApp(config);

    this.auth = app.auth();
    this.db = app.database();
  }

  doPasswordUpdate = password =>
    this.auth.currentUser.updatePassword(password);
}
 
export default Firebase;
```

The error I get (in VSCode) is:

```
Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'.
```

Presumably this is because I've said that doPasswordUpdate should return void, which obviously doesn't have a "then" property.  But what should I use instead of void?  Is there something that does have a "then"? Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37986102/property-then-does-not-exist-on-type-void)

Comment: `doPasswordUpdate` is a function that returns `Promise<void>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are telling TypeScript lies about your `firebase` object.

```
interface FormProps {
  firebase: {
    doPasswordUpdate: (string) => void  // Not sure about this line
  }
}
```

Explicitly tells the code that `doPasswordUpdate` does not have a return value.

Instead, you should just use your class's declaration by importing it and then using it.

```
// import the class declaration
import Firebase, { withFirebase } from '../Firebase';

interface FormProps {
  // tell the compiler that your firebase is a Firebase
  firebase: Firebase
}
```

This way, the compiler knows to look at your `Firebase` class for the type information regarding `doPasswordUpdate`.

Answer (score 1):

In VSCode you can press CTRL, move your cursor over `updatePassword` and see the function's definition. Use return type instead of `void` in your function.